# How to get selected in list of dropdown in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i have object that i want created to list of dropdown like this

```
$scope.cars = [
    [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Lambo", color : "red"}            
    ]
    ,
    [
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white"},
            {model : "Ferarri", color : "orange"}           
    ],
    [
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"},
            {model : "Nissan", color : "blue"}            
    ]
];
```

my UI code like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in cars">
<select ng-model="selectedCars[$index]" ng-options="car.model for car in data">
</select>
```

now i want access the selected item for each dropdwon, anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use different **`variablename`** for ng-model and you could access using **`$scope.variablename`**

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="car.model for car in data">
   <option value="x"></option>
</select>
```

and in controller,

```
console.log($scope.selected);
```

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('testController',function($scope){
$scope.select = [];
$scope.cars = [
    [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Lambo", color : "red"}            
    ]
    ,
    [
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "white"},
            {model : "Ferarri", color : "orange"}           
    ],
    [
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"},
            {model : "Nissan", color : "blue"}            
    ]
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
<div ng-repeat="data in cars">
<select  ng-init="select[$index]=data" ng-model="select[$index]" ng-options="car.model for car in data">
</select>
 <div ng-repeat="tmp in select track by $index">
      {{tmp}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi it's working fine if i don't repeat the dropdown, please see if i use repeat to generate dropdownlist

    <div ng-repeat="data in cars">

so, what i mean is, i want access all of selected dropdown and bundle it in variabel like $scope.DropdownDataSelected

Comment: check the demo above

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for - '**binding an array as model for list of dropdowns**'

use syntax `ng-options="car.model as car.model for car in data"`, this will bind the `model` property of `car` object to ng-model of you select element.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in cars">
    <select ng-model="selectedCars[$index]" ng-options="car.model as car.model for car in data">
    </select>
</div>
{{selectedCars}}
```

sample [plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DhfkHLIZkwaVG9tfC5mM?p=preview).